# ShellLauncher move app to c:/windows/system32

Tags: powershell

I defined a Kiosk mode using shell launcher and a powershell script from Windows 10. I have an application on a specific location on pc. When that app is started by shellLauncher it consider `C:\Windows\system32` as current directory even if the application is not there. Because of this application tries to find some files there but there are not in `C:\Windows\system32`.

I expected to consider as Current Directory the location where is the executable file not the `C:\Windows\system32`.

Why in kiosk mode the executable is somehow moved to `C:\Windows\system32` ? how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: The executables aren't moved to 'system32', the current directory is set to this.  One thing to try is to add some code (e.g. `Set-location C:\Temp`) in the 'AllUsersAllHosts' [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6).  Profiles are executed early in the session initialisation, so the path should be set properly once your code/commands executes later.

Comment: By default the current directory is to system32? because if i run the same executable from a normal login user it works, but from ShellLauncher it doens't.

Comment: I don't know anything about the 'ShellLauncher' as it's nothing to do with the 'PowerShell' tag you put on your question.  However, if I run PowerShell.exe normally on my Windows 10 system, it defaults to my 'home drive' as the current path, but if I right-click and select 'Run as Administrator' (and accept the UAC prompt), the current directory is 'C:\windows\system32'.  So it's no surprise to me that some other app might set an unexpected path.